# Firing events in Cordova applications

Tags: javascript, cordova, events, dom-events

I am trying to trigger events (`backbutton`, `pause`, `resume` etc) in cordova manually from the browser (for debugging). I am doing it in the following way:

```
$(window).trigger('backbutton');
```

When we register the event handler using `$(document).on('backbutton', handlerCode);`

The `backbutton` event gets triggered, however when we register it using the syntax in the cordova documentation:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
```

the event handler is not triggered. I noticed this when I used `$(window).trigger('backbutton')`, the code did not hit the cordova.js file. What would be the right way to invoke events in cordova application from the browser?

Comment: Try `cordova.fireDocumentEvent('backbutton')` and see if that works better?

Comment: Tried     cordova.fireDocumentEvent('backbutton') also, but the control did not return to the event handler for the backbutton

Comment: You said "What would be the right way to invoke events in cordova application from the browser?". You can't test those events on the browser, you need a phone

Comment: Yes, but my requirement is to simulate firing events in browser during development, before creating the app and deploying to the phone. All I need is a way to fire events so that after firing events, the control returns to the event handler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to fire the events from browser. In order to fire the events, it is required to either fireWindowEvent or fireDocumentEvent.

To fire the pause, resume, online, offline, backbutton, menubutton, searchbutton, startcallbutton, endcallbutton, volumeupbutton, volumedownbutton, use the fireDocumentEvent. eg, firing 'pause' event:-

```
cordova.fireDocumentEvent('pause',{});
```

In order to fire events related to battery, use fireWindowEvent. eg, firing 'batterycritical' event:-

```
cordova.fireWindowEvent('batterycritical', {"level":"20","isPlugged":true});
```