# Show battery level using meteor/cordova and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I want to display the current battery level on an iPhone using meteor/cordova and react.

[This](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/reference/cordova-plugin-battery-status/) is the plugin I use.

This is how I imagined it to work:

```
export default class BatteryDetails extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.currentBatteryLevel = 0;

    function onBatteryStatus(status) {
        this.currentBatteryLevel = status.level;
    }

    window.addEventListener("batterystatus", onBatteryStatus, false);
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('batterystatus'));
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            Remaining: {this.currentBatteryLevel}
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: In your `render` method, you have tried to render `this.getBatteryLevel()` - however, it looks like this function does not `return` any value.

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone for something more traditional, though I can't test it right now :

```
export default class BatteryDetails extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentBatteryLevel: 0
    };

    window.addEventListener("batterystatus", (status) => this.onBatteryStatus(status), false);
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('batterystatus'));
  }

  onBatteryStatus(status) {
    this.setState({ currentBatteryLevel: status.level });
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        Remaining: { this.state.currentBatteryLevel } 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately, it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Phil see my edit, I forgot `status` parameter. Anyway, do you get any error ?

Comment: @ Nathan P.: I got a reference error, stating that the variable `onBatteryStatus` could not be resolved- if I remember correctly. I moved its declaration into the constructor and no longer get errors, but it still won't work.

Comment: @Phil Edited again, sorry

Comment: No problem :-) Just copy-pasted your latest version: Not working, no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think I used that package in a PhoneGap project (and not a Meteor project), and I encountered some problems with the `batterystatus` event. I think it was like this:

When subscribing to the event the first time, it is fired immediately. It also works like this the next time you subscribe to it, but only if you have unsubscribe your first event listener. If you have done this mistake (and forget unsubscribing), you need to restart the app (force close it).

However, the event is always fired when you plug/unplug a charger, so that was a convenient way to test it it worked or not.

Comment: Thank you for the info- but I don't see how this could help me :) In my understanding the problem is that the correct value is gone after the event has been triggered.

Comment: Ah, I now see that you use `dispatchEvent`. I haven't check the source code, but I doubt `cordova-plugin-battery-status` listens for that event and dispatches a real `batterystatus` event (when you dispatch an event, it will be dispatched precisely as it is, e.g. it will not have a `level` property).

Comment: Logging `status.level` inside `onBatteryStatus` does show the correct result though. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to tell me though :)

Comment: Ok, then you probably don't have the problem I did. Is your `onBatteryStatus` callback called twice? And it has a correct value the first time, but not the second time? Then you should remove `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('batterystatus'))` (which I don't think make any sense here, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27123026/2104665).